# How to assigning a value into Task<EventCallback> type field

Tags: c#

Forgive me if this is a stupid question but this is what I want if possible. I want to assign a method or function into a field of another class of type Task.

I have a code something like this

```
public class Class1 {
    public async Task ShowDataAsync() {
        //some code here
    }
}

Class1 class1 = new Class1();


public class Class2 {
    public Task<EventCallback> SomethingAsync { get; set; }
}

Class2 class2 = new Class2 ();
class2.SomethingAsync = class1.ShowDataAsync;
```

Visual Studio is complaining with:
`Cannot convert method group 'ShowDataAsync' to non-delegate type Task<EventCallback>. Did you intend to invoke the method?`

Comment: Change the return type of `ShowDataAsync` to `Task<EventCallback>`.

Comment: @bolkay are you saying I want to call the method? Did you really read and understand my scenario? I am assigning a valur not running it.

Comment: Sorry @user3856437. I thought I deleted the comment. Done that now. All the best.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
public class Class2 {
    public Func<Task> SomethingAsync { get; set; }
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend to use this kind of design, as it is confusing and allows method to be changed unexpectedly.

Comment: I came approach to that design because actually the Class2 is going to be passed to another same as with other Class2 fields of type either int, double, and string.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I used this but why is it that when I invoke the method in another object, it outputs an error:

```Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
      Unhandled exception in circuit 'bElbYkKrMGYWAAoh-Cokdt9rkh4cRhSBXuJLJq7K9Bs'.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.```

Here's how I invoke it:

```await class3.SomethingMethodAsync.Invoke();```

Comment: @user3856437 I would say that is error completely unrelated to the code I suggested. What exactly are you calling and from where. I have a fleeting suspicion the saved method is being called from place where it was never intended to. Which is, not surprisingly, reason why I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Comment: I am actually using c# Blazor. The saved method is being called from another Blazor component.